# oracle pl/sql block throwing ORA-00922: missing or invalid option

Tags: oracle, query, plsql, errors, dynamic-sql

I have the following segment of oracle pl/sql block

```
DECLARE
    rec all_tab_columns%ROWTYPE;
    v_tableName VARCHAR2(100);
    v_columnName VARCHAR2(100);
    v_schemaName VARCHAR2(100);
BEGIN
    v_schemaName := 'TESTNEW';
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'create table '||v_schemaName||'.table_column_mapping_8(table_name varchar2(100), column_name varchar2(100));';
    for rec in (
        SELECT table_name, column_name FROM all_tab_columns WHERE identity_column = 'YES' AND OWNER = v_schemaName
    ) LOOP
         v_tableName := rec.table_name;
         v_columnName := rec.column_name;

        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'insert into ' ||v_schemaName||'.table_column_mapping_8 values('''||v_tableName||''', '''|| v_columnName ||''');';
      END LOOP;
END;
```

As I try running this, I get the following error:

Error report -
ORA-00922: missing or invalid option
ORA-06512: at line 8
00922. 00000 -  "missing or invalid option"
*Cause:
*Action:

Looks like something is wrong at the execute immediate statment

Tried to google it and found this:
http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_ora_00922_missing_or_invalid_option.htm

Couldn't find the real cause.

Can someone help here?

Thanks in advance

Comment: @basha04 the '.' separates the schema from the table. Otherwise how would I tell to the engine that a table needs to be created in a particular schema if there are many schemas?

Comment: It hink the string of the Execute Imemdiate statement should not end with a '"'. But I am not sure and have not the time to investigate this

Comment: @miracle173 I think you are referring to the second execute immediate statement and  the block fails at the first statement itself. Moreover, in the second statement also, it's 3 single quotes( '''), used to specify the character values not single quote -double quote-single quote('"').

Comment: No I am referring to the first statement, too `'create table '||v_schemaName||'.table_column_mapping_8(table_name varchar2(100), column_name varchar2(100));'`ends with a `;`

Comment: @miracle173 that doesn't seem to be an issue. It's there to mark the end of create statement as there are insert statements after it. If I don't use ; I get an error stating sql statement not ended properly.

Comment: why don't you print out the assembled statements to see what _really_ is being executed?

Comment: You should provide a [minimal-complete-and-verifiable-example](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2990/minimal-complete-and-verifiable-example). If you think the problem is in the create-table then you should remove all othere things that are not necessary to demonstrate your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the semicolon at the end of the `execute immediate` DDL string. Oracle SQL doesn't have statement terminators - semicolons are only used by client tools and the PL/SQL language, and your DDL string is not PL/SQL.

This fails due to the unrecognised semicolon character:

```
begin
    execute immediate 'create table demo (id int);';
end;
```

This works:

```
begin
    execute immediate 'create table demo (id int)';
end;
```

You will need to do the same for the dynamic `insert` later in the block.

Comment: Thanks @William Robertson. It works